# Performance textfield over scaleSlider

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to create something that looks like an interactive bar-chart. I'm using a method that creates a figure based on a list of boxes.
I'm using scaleSlider to interactively change the number of boxes shown in my figure. Using only one bar, the performance is OK but with 4 bars, the performance is drastically reduced.

[image]

I've tried to replace scaleSlider by textfield, to see if that improves the performance. However, i need some help to get things running.

The scaledbox example below is working and results in the screenshot below.

```css
Figure scaledbox(){
   int n = 10;
   return vcat([ hcat([ scaleSlider(int() { return 0; },     
                                    int () { return 50; },  
                                    int () { return n; },    
                                    void (int s) { n = s; }, 
                                    width(200)),
                        text(str () { return "n: <n>";})
                      ], left(),  top(), resizable(false)),  
               computeFigure(Figure (){ return visualizeAllUnitSizes(n); })
               ]);
}
```

How do I implement textfield to replace the scaleSlider with a textfield input field? I've tried the tfield() example from the Rascal tutor but I'm not sure how to create a small textbox that will hold an int and will run the method that generates the figure after pressing enter.

```css
public Figure tfield(){
  str entered = "";
  return vcat([ box(textfield("", void(str s){ entered = s;}, fillColor("yellow")),  size(20,30)),
                text(str(){return "entered: <entered>";}, left())
              ]);
}
```

Comment: Just want to make clear that my O(n2) code is to blame. Sliding the slider from n = 10 to any other value will recalculate the Figure and because of the calculation time it really hard to slide to the value I want. Therefor I was wondering if a textfield would be more precise in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question;
There was a big difference in performance between my 2015 iMac 5K model and my 2016 MacBook Pro. On my MBP the slider ran smoothly, on my iMac the slider was barely usable. So the performance issue is probably related to the high resolution of my iMac.